# Delete an object by id with django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Working on school project. I am trying to delete messages by only the people that were logged in and have created it. I want other user to see them but only the creator can delete it. I have code that will delete everything in the database. I researched and found that Mysecret.objects.filter(id=request.session['user_id']).delete()  should work but when i do this the page wont delete anything just refreshes the page.

I will only post views and model as i know everything else works. I think its just the format that I cant seem to nail down.

SO what I have gotten up to now is I have my message id which is secret.id and i have the creators id which is secret.creator.id   and the session id request.session['user_id'].
 how do i compare them to delete only tha tmessage

```
Views.py 

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . models import Mysecret
from ..logReg.models import User


# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    context = {

    "secret": Mysecret.objects.all(),

    }

    return render(request, 'secretdojo/index.html', context)


def create(request):
    secreteid= User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])

    Mysecret.objects.create( secret=request.POST['message'], creator=secreteid)

    return redirect( 'secretdojo:index')

def removesecret(request):


    Mysecret.objects.filter(id=request.session['user_id']).delete()



    return redirect( 'secretdojo:index')


def topsecret(request):
    context = {


    }

    return redirect( '/')

model.py 


from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from ..logReg.models import User

class Mysecret(models.Model):
    secret = models.CharField(max_length =500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    loguser = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='loguser')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='creator')
```

The foreignKey part of the User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length =100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: please post mysecret model too

Comment: If `creator` contains the creator then why are you comparing the user to `id`?

Comment: ta is the my seceret model

Comment: because that id is only in the other def i doesn't follow down. At least when i tried that it broke

Answer (score 1):

You should something like this :

```
Mysecret.objects.filter(creator=request.user).delete()
```

Comment: @DavidHollenbeck : it would work fine if you use Django Auth.. or make changes changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion:** don't keep your own User model, but use the [Django's Authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/)

In terms of your code I believe you "create" code also doesn't work and it is because of this line `Mysecret.objects.filter(id=request.session['user_id'])`. As this will not return anything. You are searching in model Mysecret, but with User ID, which will not return anything. Instead you need to have:

```
 Mysecret.objects.filter(creator=request.session['user_id'])
```

If you use Danjgo's Auth, you will have `request.user` and can do following:

```
 Mysecret.objects.filter(creator=request.user)
```

**One other note:** What is the reason of having `loguser` field for Mysecret model? It seems redundant for your case,

Comment: its for a many to many for the loguser for more apps later to be added. and your method above does not break but does not delete just refreshes the page.

Comment: Please try debugging by printing the value of `Mysecret.objects.filter(creator=request.session['user_id'])` to see what does it return. If it returns None, then your query doesn't work. Are you sure that you store your user ID in the session?

Comment: I know im getting the id due to the fact that I have them printing currently in my html 
Id user Id message Course Name Date Added Action
24 1 This is a test I hope it works March 22, 2017, 10:50 a.m. 
Remove
25 1  March 22, 2017, 11:12 a.m. 
Remove
26 1  March 22, 2017, 11:16 a.m. 
Remove

Comment: Can you please try printing the result of your query in the view and look in the log to see what it prints?

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the messages created by creator

```
Mysecret.objects.filter(creator=request.session['user_id']).delete()
```

To delete message by id and only by its creator

eg: assume secret_id is the id of the message

```
Mysecret.objects.filter(creator=request.session['user_id'],id =secret_id ).delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows.

```
mainid = Mysecret.objects.get(id=id)
userid =User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])

if mainid.creator != userid:
    return False
mainid.delete()

 <td>{{ dog.created_at }}</td>
                {% if dog.creator.id == request.session.user_id %}
                <td><form action="{% url 'secretdojo:remove' id=dog.id %}">{% csrf_token %}<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Remove"></form></td> 
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> To Delete a specific product from the session cart by id:

`
def DeleteProductView(request,id):

```
cart = request.session.get('cart')
product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
var = str(product.id)
if request.method == 'POST':
    request.session.modified = True
    cart.pop(var)`
```